# Android push client implementation at Expo

Tags: reactjs, node.js, firebase, expo

I am trying to set up a Push Notification Server and its respective client.

I have created a server using Node and Express and am waiting to test it. For this purpose, I am developing a client in React Native + Expo + react-native-firebase.

My goal is to create the client to conduct tests, but I am encountering several issues. When compiling it with `expo run:android` or `npx react-native-android`, I encounter the following errors:

- Using `npx react-native-android`

```
ERROR  Error: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.app().

Ensure you have:

1) imported the 'io.invertase.firebase.app.ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage' module in your 'MainApplication.java' file.

2) Added the 'new ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage()' line inside of the RN 'getPackages()' method list.

See http://invertase.link/android for full setup instructions.

This error is located at:
    in App (at withDevTools.js:18)
    in RCTView (at View.js:116)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:127)
    in RCTView (at View.js:116)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:155)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:50)
    in main(RootComponent) (at renderApplication.js:67), js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Error: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.app().
```

- Using `expo run:android`

```
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. FAILURE: Build failed with 
an exception. * What went wrong: A problem was found with the configuration of task ':react-native-firebase_app:packageDebugResources' (type 'MergeResources'). - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\Users\aamaro\Desktop\Cliente Node 6\sicongresos\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\android\build\generated\res\resValues\debug'. Reason: Task ':react-native-firebase_app:packageDebugResources' uses this output of task ':@react-native-firebase_app:generateDebugResValues' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Possible solutions: 1. Declare task ':@react-native-firebase_app:generateDebugResValues' as an input of ':react-native-firebase_app:packageDebugResources'. 2. Declare an explicit dependency on ':@react-native-firebase_app:generateDebugResValues' from ':react-native-firebase_app:packageDebugResources' using Task#dependsOn. 3. Declare an explicit dependency on ':@react-native-firebase_app:generateDebugResValues' from ':react-native-firebase_app:packageDebugResources' using Task#mustRunAfter. For more information, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency in the Gradle documentation. * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD 
FAILED in 58s.
```

I have been stuck at this point for 3 days and cannot seem to find a way out. I have seen many threads regarding this issue. Some suggest that the react-native-firebase library is not compatible with Expo, while others mention issues with the SDK compiler. Some suggest following the suggested steps and editing the MainApplication file. Or perhaps using `npx jetify`. At this point, I have tried many things and feel lost, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

##### References followed

- [Configurar React Native desde cero con Expo](https://openwebinars.net/blog/configurar-react-native-desde-cero-con-expo/)
- [Push Notification Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://scientyficworld.org/push-notification-firebase-cloud-messaging/)

Create a push client in Expo. Problem, the firebase library does not compile well for me